# How to add items to multidimensional array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to build an array of arrays which in the next step will be used as argument to `json_encode()`.

Each element in the array looks like this:

```
$element = array(
                 'ITEM_ID' => $itemID,
                 'STATUS' => $status
                )
```

An example of a desired result with two elements is:

```
array( array('ITEM_ID' => 1,'STATUS' => "ok"), array('ITEM_ID' => 2,'STATUS' => "not ok") )
```

I have tried:

```
array_push($elementArray, $element1);
array_push($elementArray, $element2);
```

But is does not give the desired result. What should I do?

Comment: `push_array` is not a PHP function. Try `array_push`. Or just `$elementArray[] = <your new item>`.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the question. Of course it was `array_push` I used in the actual code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

push_array is not a php functionyou can try with array_push() or more simple

Try with

```
$element = array(
    'ITEM_ID' => $itemID,
    'STATUS' => $status
)

$element2 = array(
    'ITEM_ID' => $itemID,
    'STATUS' => $status
)

$finalArray[] = $element;
$finalArray[] = $element2;

echo "<pre>";
print_r($finalArray);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!